# Problems on creating array variable in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I am facing the problem on how to create array in Jasper, I added new variable which should contain array. But i really do not know how to set this as array.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy.

### The report's template

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="array" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="67f7b35d-37a4-4514-9416-5496bb44561f">
    <variable name="arrVar" class="java.lang.String[]">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new String[]{"Paris", "London", "Berlin"}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="10" width="100" height="20" uuid="ea41f111-1bcf-43a0-a98e-7487906133b8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.toString($V{arrVar})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

### The result in iReport will be

[image]

#### Note

1) Don't forget to set *Java* as language for report

2) For more details about how to declare arrays in *Java* you can look at [Declare array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-java) post